# update query for mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I executed a very simple query on a mysql master -

```
update test_db.test_table set name = "Crystal" where id=20;
```

which worked fine and didn't get replicated on slaves. But, when the query was changed to using single quotes, it worked -

```
update test_db.test_table set name = 'Crystal' where id=20;
```

I'm trying to find out explanation why query didn't work with double quotes. Can someone point it out? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you have the `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode set differently on the master and slaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL normally allows string literals to be written using single or double quotes, although ANSI SQL only specified single quotes. If you enable the `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode, it follows the ANSI standard and only allows single quotes.

It sounds like you're using statement-based replication and have `ANSI_QUOTES` enabled on the slaves, but not the master. So the master accepts the query, but when it gets sent to the slaves they reject it.

Make sure you have all your SQL mode settings the same on your master and slaves, or use row-based replication.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation